# Why Use Namespaces (PHP)

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm not quite getting why one would need to use namespaces. Well, I've got some reasons from other people's questions but I'm not entirely sure if I understand it.

From my reading, it seems that the only reason to use namespaces is so that class names can be re-used for programs that have different modules? Is that correct?

eg) So if module "Lalaland" has a class named "pillows". I wouldn't be able to use a class named "pillows" in a different module called "Slumberland" if I were to load both modules? So the fix then would be to create a namespace Lalaland and a namespace Slumberland. Within those namespaces, I can then use class "pillows"? Did I get that right?

Comment: Have a look over at http://packagist.org/ - thousands of contributed PHP libraries. That's why we need namespaces.

Comment: Your paragraph at the bottom is basically it - namespaces guarantee uniqueness of names. Now that actually _sharing stuff_ in PHP has become common, this is really important.

Comment: But in your own program, namespaces can also inform the layout of your class hierarchy, such that you can [make use of class autoloading tools](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) that implement accepted standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, it is used to prevent naming collisions, if we did not have this and loaded to libraries php would not know which class you are talking about. This would cause either errors or just overwrite the class which would break the modules. Namespaces save you having to edit every framework that has the same name as another you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the main uses are "organizing" and "naming"

many things may call for a `parse` method or function and
instead of inventing a `parserX_parse` function or even (watch the classname) `ParserX::parse`

i.e. you could go with a namespace `ParseLibA` where a `Parser` has a `parse` method and a `SpeedParseLib` which does the same, without name-clashes